# How do i put a space between my two strings?

Tags: javascript, string, space

Sorry if this question is to basic but how do I put a space in-between my two strings using JavaScript ?

The code in question is the following

```
console.log ("myFirstString + mySecondString =  " + (myFirstString +  mySecondString));
```

The out put is coming out as "myFirstString + mySecondString =  MikeSlett"

I need there to be a space between Mike and Slett soo it reads " Mike Slett".

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Well, how did you put the space between `=` and `MikeSlett`? Any particular reason why you think string concatenation wont work on other places as well?

Comment: Just needed the "" instead of one " so now I understand :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myFirstString + " " + mySecondString
```

Answer (score 1):

In modern JavaScript you can use a template literal. Then just put a space between the variable substitutions.

```
console.log(`myFirstString + mySecondString = ${myFirstString} ${mySecondString}`)
```